# Grails, Tomcat deployment error

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, deployment, war

I am trying to deploy a war file using tomcat 7 but I get these error.

```
Feb 26, 2013 3:42:48 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.compass.core.lucene.engine.manager.DefaultLuceneSearchEngineIndexManager$11.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1599)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
    at org.compass.core.lucene.engine.manager.DefaultLuceneSearchEngineIndexManager.performScheduledTasks(DefaultLuceneSearchEngineIndexManager.java:426)
    at org.compass.core.lucene.engine.manager.DefaultLuceneSearchEngineIndexManager$ScheduledIndexManagerRunnable.run(DefaultLuceneSearchEngineIndexManager.java:527)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The same war works fine on other machines but it gives this error on production machine. I tried changing the apache server and also jdk in the machine, but no effect. Can someone please tell me what is this error related to ?

Comment: Which is the output from `localhost.2013.02.26.log`? I had the same output from `catalina.out` but actually it just says `the application is already stopped`. The cause of such stop should be in `localhost`

Comment: localhost.2013.02.26.log is empty, just some unrelated stuffs. However, I found the same thing in tomcat7-stderr.2013.02.23.log

Comment: The problem seems related to `org.compass.core.lucene.engine.manager.DefaultLuceneSearchEngineIndexManager`. Are you sure the necessary `jar` is in your classpath also on the production machine? I have no experience with Compass nor Grails, but it seems a packaging issue.

Comment: I deployed the war in an another machine, it worked! Also, I used another war (from an older version of our application) in the production machine, it worked as well!

Comment: Are you sure, you have correct JVM versions? If you build with Java 7, it will not run under 6, etc.  Also TomCat need JDK, JRE is not suficience. Also use SUN (Oracle) JDK, not OpenJDK.

Comment: I build the war using java 7 and i have installed java 7 in production machine with jdk 1.7.0. And i have the Oracle JDK.

Comment: This thread might help a tiny bit: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/searchable-tomcat6-fail-td1339718.html

Answer (score 2):

This could be a file system access rights issue. Please make sure that the path exists and that tomcat has 'write' rights on the location where Searchable/Lucene is trying to create the index.